# is it possible to clone or copy thead and end up with th of same width jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, width

Found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/royling/Jf6fs) I and I am not sure if my assumption is correct. It is not possible to clone or copy `thead` and end up with the same `thead` with same width?

In a separate project I have the same issue.. I am creating a thead then coping the html of an original thead and putting them in a clone thead but my problem is the width are not the same.

This is how i implement my process:

```js
var i = [];


var $original = $(this).find(".spec-table__thead.spec-table__thead--original th p");
//getting width of original
$original.each(function(index) {
  i[index] = $(this).width();
});

var n = $(this).find(".spec-table__thead").html(),
  o = $('<thead class="spec-table__thead spec-table__thead--clone">' + n + "</thead>");

//creating the clone thead
var $clone = $(this).find(".spec-table__thead--clone th p");
$("#spectablecontent").on('custom-update', '.spec-table__thead--clone', //function(index) {
//  console.log(i[index])
//});

//assigning the width to cloned thead
//here im not getting the width from the original thead correctly 
$clone.each(function(index) {
  console.log(i[index])
  $(this).width(i[index]);
});
```

Comment: You could try `$(cloneth).css("width", i[index])` - but the widths will depend on how they are defined in the first place.  `<table>`s generally auto-fit their content unless they have been instructed otherwise (eg via a `<col>`).  So your clone could just be auto-fitting

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah i think thats my main problem how to get the correct width from the original thead. is there any other way of doing this ?